# Why this function append list in standard ml can't work?

Tags: sml

In ocaml,this can work:

```
# let a b c=b@[c];;
val a : 'a list -> 'a -> 'a list = <fun>
# a [1] 2;;
- : int list = [1; 2]
```

when use sml(sml/nj):

```
- fun a(b,c)=b@[c];;
val a = fn : 'a list * 'a -> 'a list
- a [1] 2;;
stdIn:4.1-4.8 Error: operator and operand do not agree [tycon mismatch]
operator domain: 'Z list * 'Z
operand:         'Y[INT] list
in expression:
a (1 :: nil)
```

I saw 《ml for the working programmer》page 258:

```
fun enq(q,x)=q@[x]
```

so why got this error in sml?Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the OCaml example, you've written the function in a curried style. This is to be expected, as this is the idiomatic style for that language.

This style works in SML, but passing tuples to functions is more idiomatic. You've defined `a` this way.

*Code mildly edited for readability.*

```
fun a(b, c) = b @ [c];
```

However, when calling it, you're using a curried style.

```
a [1] 2;
```

This is an understandable error when moving back and forth between OCaml and SML, but it explains the issue you're seeing.

Rather you should be writing:

```
a([1], 2);
```

Or you can define `a` in SML in the same curried style that you used in OCaml:

```
fun a b c = b @ [c];
```